# Vector subspace of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have a set of polynomials of degree at most $2$, such that $p(x) \geq 0$ for any real $x$.

It isn't a vector subspace because I can multiply by a negative number such that $p(x) < 0$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: If degree is greater than 2, it's still not a vector subspace? Because I'm thinking, $p(x) \geq 0$ means to calculate the value of a polynomial function at point $x$.

Comment: The bound on the degree is irrelevant. No set of polynomials with that property can be a subspace so long as it contains a non zero polynomial, because if $p$ belongs to it, then $-p$ doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bound on the degree is irrelevant. If $S$ is a set of polynomials such that $p(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ and all $p\in S$, then $S$ is not a subspace so long as it contains a nonzero polynomial: for that polynomial you would have $p(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0$ and therefore $-p(x_0)<0$, so $-p\notin S$.

So the only choice is $S=\{0\}$.

Comment: So the null polynomial is a vector subspace?

Comment: @0kelvin Yes, of course.